# Why does it seem that the List Scaffold Template does not respect the DisplayName attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Should I be using some other attrbute that the List template respects, or am I stuck having to manually change the source to DisplayFor(m => m.someProperty) ?

I read in another thread a suggestion that ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText should be used, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I want the IDE's Add View wizard to work for Lists as it does for the other scaffold templates, and I'm hoping there's an attribute i could use on my properties to get that done.

Comment: List template, are you talking about the scaffold that comes automatically generated using the `Add View` dialog? If so then the actual `DisplayFor` is `DisplayFor(m => item.SomeProperty)`.

Comment: Right, but DisplayFor can't be used in the column headers (the TH elements generated automatically); because the model is an IEnumerable. What I'm looking for is to have the IDE automatically populate the header columns with the correct names found in DisplayName attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the list could be empty and with an empty list you have no access to the an instance of the type you're getting the display name for. As a result you lose typed access to the particular property you're referencing.

For instance how would you know which property to use the display name for if you don't have access to the object

```
<th>@Html.DisplayFor(f => f....,
            /* 
              how do you get the property you want to
              access here if the list is empty
            */
    )</th>
```

You could write an extension method that would accept the model type of course but you'll lose that typed access.

```
public static IHtmlString DisplayType(this HtmlHelper html, Type modelType, string propertyName) {
    object modelInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(modelType);
    var data = ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression(propertyName, 
                      new ViewDataDictionary(modelInstance));
    return new HtmlString(data.DisplayName ?? propertyName);
}


@Html.DisplayType(typeof(CoolModel), "Name")
```

Though I don't really recommend it.

small update - you could also access it via the model as well but still without typed access:

```
public static IHtmlString DisplayType<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
          Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, 
          string propertyName) where TModel : IEnumerable {
    object modelInstance = 
              Activator.CreateInstance(expression.Body.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0]);

    var data = ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression(propertyName, 
                          new ViewDataDictionary(modelInstance));
    return new HtmlString(data.DisplayName ?? propertyName);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, so here's the million dollar question; how do I extend Visual Studio to generate your HtmlHelper extension when I want to autogenerate my List views so that I don't have to do it manually? Is it even possible to do?

Comment: You'll have to create your own T4 template using [MvcScaffolding](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MvcScaffolding) which is something, I'm sorry to say, I have little experience with. Here's a [blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) with more info.

Comment: Thanks, I'll certainly look into it! by the way, I rewrote the extension so that instantiating an instance would not be necessary.

Comment: public static IHtmlString DisplayType(
        this HtmlHelper html,
            Type modelType,
            string propertyName)
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo = modelType.GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (propertyInfo != null)
    {
        DisplayNameAttribute attr = system.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(propertyInfo, typeof(DisplayNameAttribute)) as DisplayNameAttribute;
        if (attr != null)
        {
            propertyName = attr.DisplayName;
        }
    }
    return new HtmlString(propertyName);
}

Comment: I'd like a similar solution using the 'this HtmlHelper<TModel> html' version, but I'm having trouble determing the model type of the IEnumerable that TModel is. Any help ?

Comment: The thing is for automatic property inference you'll need to pass that Expression otherwise your call will have to look like `Html.DisplayType<SomeNamespace.SomeModel>("propertyName")`. I prefer the `f => f` syntax myself :) (i don't think razor supports that syntax anyway)